# Android Maps v2 with Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-maps-v2

Im having a problem inserting `NavigationDrawer` to my application. heres some part of the code

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener, LocationSource {
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private OnLocationChangedListener mListener;
..
}
```

In its activity type, i cant insert the navigation drawer. All I want for the navigation drawer is not to change fragments because im only using the drawer for showing markers by type, change normal map to satelite.
Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Create a new project in Eclipse with a NavigationDrawer structure, so you will get the default code for a good implementation of navigation drawer. Then you can merge this sample code and your existing.

The method you need to customise to your needs is, in MainActivity:

```
@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1))
            .commit();
}
```

Instead of replacing the fragments, just switch between your markers/layers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it solved this by merging my code of a drawer properly.